# iOS 8 iPad Mini Orientation thinks It should be landscape despite it being disabled

Tags: unity, ios, ipad, orientation

I've only enabled portrait mode in the info.plist and generally the iPad Mini running my game works fine except if I quickly change its physical orientation from landscape to portrait, the app reorients itself incorrectly like what happened to this person: http://answers.unity3d.com/storage/temp/33155-screen+shot+2014-10-01+at+8.25.25+am.png (see screenshots, but the repro is different in my case).

I've tried hard setting the orientation (Screen.orientation = portrait, etc, etc) but looks like it's just ignored..